# How can I format a value with thousands (,) in the DataTable, I am using the JavaScript highcharts.com library?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am trying to format my dataTable with thousands or with (,). but I have not been able to, I have seen forums and I have not been able to, I will share my code with you. The variable Venta is theq
I want to format data: sale both in the graph and in the dataTable.

````
<div class="">
    <figure class="highcharts-figure">
        <div id="container"></div>
    </figure>
</div>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
<script>
Highcharts.chart('container', {
     chart: {
         type: 'column'
     },
     title: {
         text: 'Ventas Mensuales',
         align: 'left',
         style: {
             fontSize: '16px' 
         }
     },
     xAxis: {
         categories: mes, // What returns mes is ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre','Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'];
         crosshair: true,
         accessibility: {
             description: 'Meses'
         }
     },
     yAxis: {
         min: 0,
         title: {
             text: 'Ventas Mensuales'
         }
     },
     tooltip: {
         valueSuffix: ' (COP)'
     },
     plotOptions: {
         column: {
             pointPadding: 0.2,
             borderWidth: 0,
             dataLabels: {
                 enabled: true,
                 formatter: function() {
                     return '$' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);
                 }
             }
         }
     },
     series: [{
         name: 'Ventas',
         data: venta // What returns is ['1356940858.000000', '1945419126.000000', '934706589.000000', '1803607453.000000', '78415027.000000'] 
         // data: valoresY
     }],
     data: {
         table: 'datatable'
     },
     exporting: {
         tableCaption: "Tabla de Ventas Mensualesss"
     }

 });
</script>```

Esperaba el valor del dataTable export formateado en miles
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extend the `export-data` module to do formatting on the values that are presented in the data table, for example like this ([see JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/ug76r0ap/)):

```
(function(H) {
  const Chart = H.Chart;
  H.wrap(Chart.prototype, 'getDataRows', function(proceed, multiLevelHeaders) {
    const result = proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

    for (const x of result) {
      console.log(x, x.length)
      for (let i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (typeof x[i] === 'number') {
          x[i] = "$" + H.numberFormat(x[i], 0)
        }
      }
    }

    return result;
  });
}(Highcharts));

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    data: [100000, 200000, 300000, 400000, 500000, 600000, 700000, 800000, 900000, 1000000]
  }],
});
```

The caveat here is that it breaks sorting by that column, because it no longer compares numbers, but rather it compares strings. The simple approach to this is to disable sorting with `allowTableSorting` ([API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.allowTableSorting)). A complicated variation is to only disable sorting by the series values, which is another extension, for example like this (included in JSFiddle above):

```
(function(H) {
  H.addEvent(Chart, 'afterViewData', function() {
    const div = this.dataTableDiv
    const row = div.querySelector('thead tr');
    if (row) {
      for (let x = 1; x < row.childNodes.length; x++) {
        const th = row.childNodes[x]
        const table = th.closest('table');
        th.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        });
      }
    }
  }, {
    order: -1
  });
}(Highcharts));
```

Comment: Thank  you very much, it is very useful, I did not know that you could extend the `export-data` module to format the values presented in the data table.

Comment: I propose this since the API does not seem to offer it. I used [the source code](https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.src.js) to find the potential [extension](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the chart values to have thousands separator you can set them by setting global options:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {thousandsSep: ','}
});
```

If you want to format label, you can pass custom formatting after the value so in your case:

```
yAxis: {
    labels: {
        format: '{value:,.0f}'
    }
}
```

Put all together example:

```js
Highcharts.setOptions({
  lang: {
    thousandsSep: ','
  }
});
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  yAxis: {
    labels: {
      format: '{value:,.0f}'
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],
  },
  series: [{
    data: [1000000, 2000000, 3000000, 4000000, 5000000]
  }]
});
```

```html
<div class="">
<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
</figure>
</div>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
```

Comment: 1. Thank you very much, it has helped me to format the graph with separators in thousands, that part already worked for me.

2. Now I want to format the dataTable that implements the Higchart library specifically this part 
`<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>`
in which it shows me a dataTable in the graph menu (view data table).
[enter image description here][1]
[enter image description here][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQ5Uy.png

  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8uEB.png

Comment: Each question should focus on one problem

Comment: That was what I wanted from the beginning, I don't know if I was clear.